# How to order and group custom post type posts by year and month

Tags: custom-post-types, order

I am building an event calendar and trying to create a filter bu month & year. 
I have custom post type named "event-calendar" and need to have 5 events per row as i have them in a slider.
So need to create the below structure

```
October 2017
  Post 1
  Post 2
  Post 3
  Post 4
  Post 5
November 2017
  Post 1
  Post 2
  Post 3
  Post 4
  Post 5
.............
January 2018
  Post 1
  Post 2
  Post 3
  Post 4
  Post 5
```

Tried to do with archives and custom sql query but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'event-calendar',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'paged' => $paged
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ($query->have_posts()){
        // do stuff
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the snippet @Oliver adams but it is not displaying the post type posts in the way i need.

Comment: hey @Oliver adams that is not the thing. I updated the post type to be mine but it not showing anything and the page is being in endless loop/load.